# django with celery error：No result backend is configured

Tags: django, redis, celery

my version:
Django==3.2
celery==5.1.2

my settings.local:
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://@127.0.0.1:6379/1'

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
# # 设置环境变量
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cmdb.settings.local')
# 实例化
# app = Celery('celeryPro', include=['message.tasks'])
app = Celery('celeryPro', backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1')
# app = Celery('cmdb')

# namespace='CELERY'作用是允许你在Django配置文件中对Celery进行配置
# 但所有Celery配置项必须以CELERY开头，防止冲突
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
# app.config_from_object(config, namespace='CELERY')
# 自动从Django的已注册app中发现任务
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request:{0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

always get the error

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is incorrect in two ways.

1. You are adding the `backend` only when creating the instance of celery **and** also calling the `config_from_object`, as per the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/application.html#config-from-object), any previous configuration is reset.
2. You are passing the incorrect config file to the `config_from_object` method. You need to send the file that Celery should use and *not* the one
   that Django uses. You can find more info in the [configuration docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/application.html#configuration).

As an example, you can have your `celery.py` file configured as below:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
# # 设置环境变量
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cmdb.settings.local')
# 实例化
# app = Celery('celeryPro', include=['message.tasks'])
# app = Celery('celeryPro', backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1')
app = Celery('cmdb')

# namespace='CELERY'作用是允许你在Django配置文件中对Celery进行配置
# 但所有Celery配置项必须以CELERY开头，防止冲突
app.config_from_object('celery_config', namespace='CELERY')
# app.config_from_object(config, namespace='CELERY')
# 自动从Django的已注册app中发现任务
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request:{0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

and your `celery_config.py` file could be something like below:

```py
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
```

Having your configuration for celery in a different file allows for more flexibility when you want to extend the configuration.

NOTE - you should keep the `celery_config.py` file in the root directory of the project i.e., in the same location as the `manage.py` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This really needs to be improved.

In addition, I found that I executed the command on the windows machine without adding "- P eventlet". The problem has been solved

Comment: Do to mean the answer needs to be improved? Sorry, your comment wasn't clear to me.

Comment: My celery read the configuration from Django's settings configuration , and I added the "- P eventlet" parameter to start celery worker , which can also work well. And I find what you said is also a good improvement for my test project.